# Limiting silver-searcher to only search specific file types

Tags: ack

I'm doing `ag "active_record" .`, but I want to only care about `.rb` files.

How do I limit what file types it searches on the command line?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Succintly,

`ag active_record --ruby`

Also you can use:

`ag --list-file-types` to list the supported file types

Otherwise you can limit by extension (also for unknown filetypes) by providing a regex as follows:

`ag -G'\.rb$' active_record`

**Edited** due to correction by bobbaluba

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I think it should be `ag active_record --ruby`.

Comment: It's `-G`, not `-g`.